# Finding the indexes of the N maximum values across an axis in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, argmax

I know that there is a method .argmax() that returns the indexes of the maximum values across an axis.

But what if we want to get the indexes of the 10 highest values across an axis?

How could this be accomplished?

E.g.:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((50, 40)))
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: you should provide a sample result that you want because the question can be interpenetrated differently. Is it the sum of 10 highest number in a row? or 10 highest in a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `argsort`:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.permutation(30))
sorted_indices = s.argsort()
top_10 = sorted_indices[sorted_indices < 10]
print(top_10)
```

Output:

```
3     9
4     1
6     0
8     7
13    4
14    2
15    3
19    8
20    5
24    6
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, say, if you want to get the index of the top 10 largest numbers of column `col`:

```
data[col].nlargest(10).index
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. This will take the 10 largest values across a row and put them into a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((50, 40)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values)[:,-10:])
```